# Trilateration on a Sphere, given 2 points and 2 distances

Tags: geodesy, trilateration

Given the points:

```
A) N 38° 38.000 W 90° 20.000
B) N 38° 39.000 W 90° 21.000
```

(I can calculate the distance between the 2 using a spherical earth model as 7710 feet, though it's not particularly relevant.)

Given those points and 2 other distances, say 4,000 ft and 5,000 ft, how do a find the 2 points that are 4,000 feet from point A and 5,000 feet from point B (thus forming one triangle to the north east and one triangle to the south west.

[image: map]

Any help converting coordinate systems if I need to is appreciated as well, and extra credit if you can point me towards a .Net library, c# function or Java function.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, unfortunately, requires spherical trigonometry.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_trigonometry
- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalTrigonometry.html

It is like normal trig, just more complex. You will need to know some things like eccentricities (maybe, but perhaps that's only if you have different heights... I gladly have never need to apply what I learnt about this!)

What I would do, though I'm not sure this is the best way, is to find one of the angles between a known point and each of the unknowns (it will be the same both sides, I think), then use that along with the distance to work out coordinates of the destination.

More reading:
 - http://www.astro.uvic.ca/~tatum/celmechs/celm3.pdf
 - http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/GreatCircleAlgorithms

Comment: Not homework... geocaching puzzle. I haven't taken a math class in 16 years!

Comment: Well, I like math, and I hate spherical trig! What about simply scaling on a map? Get in Google Earth and plot your two points, then use a ruler in GE to work out approximate new coordinates. That's much easier than the math (though the math isn't too hard!).

Comment: That won't work... this is part of a puzzle that will involve a recursive algorithm that will have to run this calculation several million times. Afraid I'll need a formula. I appreciate the tips though, that should help me check my work.

Comment: How precisely located is the geocache? Is it buried? If you created a custom UTM projection centered on your area of interest and entered your points, you would get a nearly distortion-free Euclidean coordinate system that's accurate to within a few feet.

Comment: When I solve the puzzle, I should have the answer to within a foot of the cache location, if I use the same spherical earth model used to create the puzzle. The location could be anywhere in a 20 mile radius though, which means taking a short cut with the geometry could send me bushwhacking in the wrong place forever. Solving this will require several nights of writing brute-force problem solving algorithms, so I feel like should get the basic calculations right if I'm going to go through all that trouble.